# Can you get LESS files to LiveReload with Grunt in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, less, gruntjs

I use MAMP/Grunt/SublimeText/LESS/LiveReload at home, which works perfectly in Chrome. Instant reloads everytime I save any designated file.

But at work, I'm working in Eclipse with files and a jetty server. Now, for some reason, when I save a 'watched' file, all the LESS is compiled and minified, and the local server refreshes itself in the browser, but it takes 20-30 seconds (and another page reload) to get a simple CSS change to implement.

Here's my gruntfile. Any ideas on how I could get changes to render more quickly?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

    project: {
        name: 'web-standard',
        version: grunt.option('pomVersion') || 'VERSION',
    },

    /* CSS */

    less: {
        build: {
            files: [
                    {   
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    src: 'src/main/less/*.less',
                    dest: 'target/css',
                    ext: '.css'
                    }
                    ]
        }
    },

    autoprefixer: {
        build: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 2 versions']
            },
            expand:true,
            flatten:true,
            src: 'target/css/*.css',
            dest: 'target/css/' 
        }
    },

    cssmin: {
        minify: {
            options: {
                banner: '<%= project.copyright %>'
            },
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'target/css/',
            src: '*.css',
            dest: 'target/css-min/',
            ext: '.min.css'
        }
    },



    /* Utilities */

    watch: {

        less: {
            options: {
                livereload:true,
                spawn: false
            },
            files: ['src/main/less/*.less','target/css-min/*.css','Gruntfile.js'],
            tasks: ['less', 'autoprefixer','cssmin']
        }
    }

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');



grunt.registerTask('dev-css', ['less','autoprefixer','cssmin','watch:less']);
```

};

Comment: Quick question, why Jetty and not connect?

Comment: it's just what they have set up at work... I'll look into it though. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @BryceJohnson, could you point me out on how to get grunt working with eclipse? I need it for auto-compiling my .less files into .css when changes ocurr. You have no accepted answer on this question, so, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The files array of your watch task should not contain the `'target/css-min/*.css'` and 'Gruntfile.js`'. Most important to remove the`'target/css-min/*.css'`

Also the 'autoprefixer' ask 'cssmin' are not necessary for development.

Note that changing the less files triggers the less task, which change the `'target/css-min/*.css'` again  which triggers the reload, also the autoprefixer will change the `'target/css-min/*.css'` files again.

Try:

```
   watch: {

        less: {
            options: {
                livereload:true,
                spawn: false
            },
            files: ['src/main/less/*.less'],
            tasks: ['less']
        }
    }
```